# How to list the difference between two nested lists in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have two nested lists like this:

```
list_1 = [[5, 3, 4], [1, 5, 8], [6, 4, 2]]
list_2 = [[8, 3, 4], [1, 5, 9], [6, 7, 2]]
```

I want to list the different values from both of the nested lists, into a list like this:

```
[5,8,8,9,4,7]
```

Is there any way in Python 3 to do this?

This what I have tried:

```
list_1 = [[5, 3, 4], [1, 5, 8], [6, 4, 2]]
list_2 = [[8, 3, 4], [1, 5, 9], [6, 7, 2]]
storer = []
for x in list_2:
    if x not in list_1:
       storer.append(x)
print(storer)
```

but it returns:

```
[[8, 3, 4], [1, 5, 9], [6, 7, 2]]
```

Comment: The [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function can do 90% of the work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

list_1 = [[5, 3, 4], [1, 5, 8], [6, 4, 2]]
list_2 = [[8, 3, 4], [1, 5, 9], [6, 7, 2]]

difflist = [a[i][j] for a in zip(list_1, list_2) for i in range(len(a)) for j in range(len(a[i])) if a[i][j] != a[i-1][j]]
print(difflist)
```

Which prints:

```
[5,8,8,9,4,7]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using `set` difference:

```
final = sum((list(set(k) - set(v)) + list(set(v) - set(k)) for k, v in zip(list_1, list_2)), [])
# [5, 8, 8, 9, 4, 7]
```

And the same result using `reduce`:

```
from functools import reduce

final = reduce(list.__iadd__, (list(set(k) - set(v)) + list(set(v) - set(k)) for k, v in zip(list_1, list_2)))
# [5, 8, 8, 9, 4, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

Later answer, but you can use `set(list_1[i]) ^ set(list_2[i])`, i.e.:

```
final = []
for i in range(len(list_1)):
    [final.append(x) for x in reversed([y for y in set(list_1[i]) ^ set(list_2[i])])]
# [5, 8, 9, 8, 7, 4]
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/XMrJJK)